# JetBrains Toolbox works very slow

Tags: developer-tools, jetbrains-toolbox

For some time JetBrains Toolbox has been working horrible slow on my PC. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Sometimes it opens normally and reacts to my clicks well, but other times it is so unusable.
Does anybody have a similar problem? How to solve it? It is really problematic for me and I see no reason why it started to has this freezes.

Comment: StackOverflow is more of meant for software development, and not actual software itself, I'd recommend posting this on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) as it is better suited there and you're more likely to get an accurate answer

Comment: @Jacob I understand your opinion, but I decided to ask about it here, because JetBrains Toolbox is strong connected with programming tools. I have also seen some other questions about this app on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to complement the answer from TravelerVihaan according to this link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-6507

You should add this section to the root of your JSON:

```json
{
    ...some your config
    "internal": {
        "graphics_api": "Software"
    }
```

Comment: Toolbox took ca 20 sec to respond to mouse clicks, but this setting fixed the issue immediately. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a working solution for that problem. To fix slow working Toolbox, you should add this entry:

```
        "graphics_api": "Software"
    }
```

to file `AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\.settings.json` (I am a Windows user, so I provided path specific for this OS). In Linux OS probably `settings.json` file location is in other place.

Comment: on Mac found it in `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/.settings.json`. Seems to be working!